# Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am developing a payment method module in Magento. When I click payment methods menu in Configuration of Magento I get the below error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in
\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php
on line 421
```

Please see the below link for the code of module which I was developing

[Magento module Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Cashondelivery_Helper_Data' not found in \xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php on line 516](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190044/magento-module-fatal-error-class-mage-cashondelivery-helper-data-not-found-in)

I am using Xampp 1.7.3 and magento 1.6.1.
Please help.

Comment: Line 421 must contain something like $object->toOptionArray(). Please post this part of the code and the part where the $object is created.

Comment: This is the core part of Magento and the error won't be in that code. Problem was in my code. Anyway its done. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your system.xml you have the following code

```
<payment_action translate="label">
    <label>Payment Action</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>cashondelivery/createorder</source_model>
    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</payment_action>
```

The source model is specified as `cashondelivery/createorder`.
According to the code you posted in the question you reference, this class is a payment method model, not a source model.
If you implement the `toOptionArray()` method on the model it would work as a system config source model as well, but that doesn't seem like a bad choice.
I would guess the source model you are looking for is something like `paygate/authorizenet_source_paymentAction`.

### Background

Source models in Magento exist to provide option lists to select and multiselects. For this purpose they implement the `toOptionArray()` method.
The options are returned as an array that has the following format:

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    return array(
        array('value' => $value1, 'label' => 'The label for option 1'),
        array('value' => $value2, 'label' => 'The label for option 2'),
        array('value' => $value3, 'label' => 'The label for option 3')
        // ... etc ...
    );
}
```

System configuration source models don't need to extend super class and don't need to implement any methods besides `toOptionArray()`.
EAV select and multiselect attributes also make use of source models, but those need to extend  `eav/entity_attribute_source_abstract` and are more complex, so I'll won't go into more details at this place.

Comment: Thank you very much Vinai. I appreciate your answers. They are well explained.

Comment: Hi Vinai, After correcting all I don't see the payment method option in Checkout page. Please help.

Comment: Add another question so this doesn't get off topic.