# Fatal error: class 'Helper_Data' not found in domainfolder/app/mage.php on line 516

Tags: php, magento

I'm getting this error in the admin panel after I log in:

> "Fatal error: Class 'Webdziner_Ajaxsearch_Helper_Data' not found in /home/hotshopl/public_html/wholesaleapparelshop.com/app/Mage.php on line 516"

I tried installing a theme into my 1.6.0.0 site and all was going good until I refreshed the cache, then it all crashed and gave me the message. http://www.wholesaleapparelshop.com I am trying to figure where this Helper file is at. I have looked at other questions and answers but I just dont seem to find a good answer to my question. I am looking everywhere.

looked at this thread but nothing http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/239818/

closest guy i can relate to is

> [Magento module Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Cashondelivery_Helper_Data' not found in \xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php on line 516](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190044/magento-module-fatal-error-class-mage-cashondelivery-helper-data-not-found-in)

Please advise help thanks

Comment: you should show the code

Comment: this is my helper file
`<?php

class Webdziner_Ajaxsearch_Helper_Data extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data
{

}`

but now i dont know how i can add it to my mage.php file so the admin panel can read it



its telling me its missing in line "516" here are lines 512-519

   `{
        $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
        if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
            $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
            self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
        }
        return self::registry($registryKey);
    }`

Answer (score 4):

You could check to see if you have Compiler enabled under System>Tools>Compiler.
If it is enabled, disable it and then flush the Magento Cache.
There after you may no longer get this error, as this is what worked for me.

You can always Enable the Compiler again afterwards.

Comment: Im soo newbie to magento..thank you sooo much for saved me after 10hours...

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to figure where this Helper file is at

It *should* be in `app/code/[pool]/Webdziner/Ajaxsearch/Helper/Data.php`, with [pool] either `local` or `community`. Keep in mind that path names are case sensitive.

If the file is definitly in this location, check the following:

- Is an opcode cache like APC installed? Then clear it and try again
- Are owners and permissions of the file set correctly? It should be readable by PHP (if unsure, compare the permissions with those of Mage.php for example)

Comment: Thanks Fab its located in local. I am trying to figure out how i can have mage.php read it. How can i code it to be read?

Comment: i am trying to access my admin panel, but i am failing at it. is there any way we can contact each other outside of this?

Comment: I am having trouble following what you mean with the APC file. I see the cache files, what should i do?

Comment: Which cache files do you see? I am not talking about Magento cache, but the PHP extension APC ([see also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911158/how-to-clear-apc-cache-entries)). Regarding "contact outside of this": If you are looking for paid consulting, visit my profile and write to `info@[my website]`

Answer (score 1):

It's not that complicated, take it easy :)

Listen,
First you must have the below code(/Helper/Data.php)

```
class Mage_Profile_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

From now, take care- it is all about where you have called the helper { Eg: Mage::helper('modulename') }. If such a call is there, then you need to have a code like:

```
<global>
......
    <helpers>
        <yournamespace_modulename>
            <class>yournamespace_modulename_Helper</class>
        </yournamespace_modulename>
    </helpers>
....
</global>
```

-in your /etc/config.xml
I mean, it is all about the 'modulename' in the helper call.

Notice: It is not that good to have more than one `<helpers>` in your /etc/config.xml.
Use it only if you are in the middle of guys running codes smarter than you.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. but i was using code for uploading file and the folder where i want to upload file, had not write permissions. So please check your code also you can give write permission to var and media folder and its sub folder and check it.