# Magento helper call from template from outside module

Tags: magento, module, magento-1.9, helper

I am using Mage::helper('addmultiple') where addmultiple is my module name Mycompany_Addmultiple_Helper_Data in Data.php in my modules helper. it gives a fatal error and why it tries to locate Mage_Addmultiple_Helper_Data instead of Mycompany_Addmultiple_Helper_Data

xml entry in my global block

```
<helpers>
    <addmultiple>
        <class>Mycompany_Addmultiple_Helper</class>
    </addmultiple>
</helpers>
```

note that when i call this from my block file or controller file from same module it is working.

I am trying to call this from some overridden core template right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

config.xml

```
<helpers>
    <addmultiple>
        <class>Mycompany_Addmultiple_Helper</class>
    </addmultiple>
</helpers>
```

Use a name for your helper class instead of default name `'Data.php'`. Here I'm using `Test.php` as the helper class.

```
class Mycompany_Addmultiple_Helper_Test extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
   // some code
   }
```

Now you can call the `Test.php` helper class as below.

```
$my_helper = Mage::helper('addmultiple/test');
```

Comment: it is looking for Mage_Addmultiple_Helper_Test by code suggested by you. i dont understand why it replaces the company name with mage

Comment: seems to have resolved. The encapsulating node in the config section should be the module name as you suggested. for complete post I read here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190044/magento-module-fatal-error-class-mage-cashondelivery-helper-data-not-found-in