# Magento : Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Giftcards_Helper_Data' not found in ...../app/Mage.php on line 546

Tags: php, magento

I have installed one module extension which throws an fatal error "Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Giftcards_Helper_Data' not found in ..../app/Mage.php on line 546" in admin.

I have reffered this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/9191286/2919940 and this link as well https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7133/3693

But I have

```
<global>
<helpers>
        <giftcards>
            <class>Webtex_Giftcards_Helper</class>
        </giftcards>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

in my config.xml and I have this class

```
class Webtex_Giftcards_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data{
// my methods
}
```

declared at "/app/code/local/Webtex/Giftcards/Helper/Data.php" path.

I have disabled compiler and cleared cache by making empty "var/cache" directory.

I found everwhere that config.xml should have helper class define and Data.php should have declare that helper class.

But I have both of them in my case, what can be reason for this error ? I have tested that module on my fresh magento installation as well,

Magento version is 1.7.0.2

Please provide help for this error ?? If there's conflicts of class names how can we debug that ??

UPDATE:
Here is my app/etc/modules/Webtex_Giftcards.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Webtex_Giftcards>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <name>Webtex Gift Cards</name>
    </Webtex_Giftcards>
</modules>
</config>
```

And here is my system.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<tabs>
    <webtex translate="label" module="giftcards">
        <label>WebTex</label>
        <sort_order>300</sort_order>
    </webtex>
</tabs>
<sections>
    <giftcards module="giftcards">
        <tab>webtex</tab>
        <label>Gift Cards</label>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>
            <default module="giftcards">
                <label>Defaults</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <min_card_value>
                        <label>Min Gift Card Value</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </min_card_value>
                    <max_card_value>
                        <label>Max Gift Card Value</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>21</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </max_card_value>
                    <show_in_shopping_cart>
                        <label>Show In Shopping Cart Page</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>22</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </show_in_shopping_cart>
                    <show_as_payment_method>
                        <label>Show As Payment Method</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>22</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </show_as_payment_method>
                    <show_mail_delivery_date_field>
                        <label>Show email delivery date field</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>23</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </show_mail_delivery_date_field>
                </fields>
            </default>
            <email module="giftcards">
                <label>Email Options</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <card_picture>
                        <label>Use default GiftCard picture for Email</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>24</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <comment>Set "No" for use product picture</comment>
                    </card_picture>
                    <email_template>
                        <label>Template for e-mail</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                        <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </email_template>
                    <print_template>
                        <label>Template for print</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                        <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </print_template>
                    <offline_template>
                        <label>Template for offline</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                        <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </offline_template>
                    <confirm_template>
                        <label>Template for confirmation</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                        <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </confirm_template>
                </fields>
            </email>
        </groups>
    </giftcards>
</sections>
</config>
```

And Here is my config.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Webtex_Giftcards>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </Webtex_Giftcards>
</modules>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <giftcards>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Webtex_Giftcards</module>
                <frontName>giftcards</frontName>
            </args>
        </giftcards>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Webtex_Giftcards before="Mage_Adminhtml">Webtex_Giftcards_Adminhtml</Webtex_Giftcards>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Webtex_Giftcards before="Mage_Checkout">Webtex_Giftcards</Webtex_Giftcards>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <giftcards>
                <file>giftcards.xml</file>
            </giftcards>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Webtex_Giftcards>
                <files>
                    <default>Webtex_Giftcards.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Webtex_Giftcards>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <giftcards_giftcards_index>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/giftcards/#]]></from>
            <to>/giftcards/giftcards/</to>
        </giftcards_giftcards_index>
        <giftcards_giftcards_balance>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/giftcards/balance/#]]></from>
            <to>/giftcards/giftcards/balance/</to>
        </giftcards_giftcards_balance>
        <giftcards_giftcards_print>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/giftcards/print/#]]></from>
            <to>/giftcards/giftcards/print/</to>
        </giftcards_giftcards_print>
        <giftcards_giftcards_apply>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/giftcards/apply/#]]></from>
            <to>/giftcards/giftcards/apply/</to>
        </giftcards_giftcards_apply>
    </rewrite>
    <models>
        <giftcards>
            <class>Webtex_Giftcards_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>giftcards_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </giftcards>
        <giftcards_mysql4>
            <class>Webtex_Giftcards_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <giftcards>
                    <table>giftcards_card</table>
                </giftcards>
                <cardslist>
                    <table>giftcards_cardlist</table>
                </cardslist>
                <order>
                    <table>giftcard_order</table>
                </order>
            </entities>
        </giftcards_mysql4>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <order>Webtex_Giftcards_Model_Sales_Order</order>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <giftcards_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Webtex_Giftcards</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </giftcards_setup>
    </resources>
    <helpers>
        <giftcards>
            <class>Webtex_Giftcards_Helper</class>
        </giftcards>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <giftcards>
            <class>Webtex_Giftcards_Block</class>
        </giftcards>
    </blocks>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <webtex_giftcards_observer_catalog_product_save_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>giftcards/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogProductSaveBefore</method>
                </webtex_giftcards_observer_catalog_product_save_after>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
        <order_cancel_after>
            <observers>
                <webtex_giftcards_observer_sales_order_cancel_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>giftcards/observer</class>
                    <method>salesOrderCancelAfter</method>
                </webtex_giftcards_observer_sales_order_cancel_after>
            </observers>
        </order_cancel_after>
        <sales_order_payment_refund>
            <observers>
                <webtex_giftcards_observer_sales_order_creditmemo_refund>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>giftcards/observer</class>
                    <method>saleOrderPaymentRefund</method>
                </webtex_giftcards_observer_sales_order_creditmemo_refund>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_payment_refund>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <webtex_giftcards_observer_sales_order_save_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>giftcards/observer</class>
                    <method>salesOrderSaveAfter</method>
                </webtex_giftcards_observer_sales_order_save_after>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>


        <sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
            <observers>
                <webtex_giftcards_observer_checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>giftcards/observer</class>
                    <method>checkoutTypeOnepageSaveOrderAfter</method>
                </webtex_giftcards_observer_checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
            </observers>
        </sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>

        <core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
            <observers>
                <webtex_giftcards_observer_checkpriceiszero>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>giftcards/observer</class>
                    <method>checkpriceiszero</method>
                </webtex_giftcards_observer_checkpriceiszero>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
        <sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
            <observers>
                <webtex_giftcards_discount_observer_testdiscountquote>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>giftcards/discount_observer</class>
                    <method>testDiscountQuote</method>
                </webtex_giftcards_discount_observer_testdiscountquote>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
    </events>
    <template>
        <email>
            <giftcards_email_email_template translate="label" module="giftcards">
                <label>Gift Card E-mail</label>
                <file>giftcard_email.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </giftcards_email_email_template>
            <giftcards_email_print_template translate="label" module="giftcards">
                <label>Gift Card Print</label>
                <file>giftcard_print.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </giftcards_email_print_template>
            <giftcards_email_offline_template translate="label" module="giftcards">
                <label>Gift Card Offline</label>
                <file>giftcard_offline.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </giftcards_email_offline_template>
            <giftcards_email_confirm_template translate="label" module="giftcards">
                <label>Gift Card Confirm</label>
                <file>giftcard_confirm.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </giftcards_email_confirm_template>
        </email>
    </template>
    <catalog>
        <product>
            <type>
                <giftcards module="giftcards">
                    <label>Gift Card</label>
                    <model>giftcards/product_type_giftcards</model> 
                    <price_model>giftcards/product_price</price_model>
                    <is_qty>1</is_qty>
                    <composite>0</composite>
                </giftcards>
            </type>
        </product>
    </catalog>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <discount>
                    <class>giftcards/discount</class>
                    <after>subtotal,shipping</after>
                    <before>grand_total</before>
                </discount>
            </totals>
        </quote>
    </sales>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <sales>
        <order>
            <create>
                <available_product_types>
                    <giftcards />
                </available_product_types>
            </create>
        </order>
    </sales>
</adminhtml>
<default>
    <giftcards>
        <email>
            <email_template>giftcards_email_email_template</email_template>
            <print_template>giftcards_email_print_template</print_template>
            <offline_template>giftcards_email_offline_template</offline_template>
            <confirm_template>giftcards_email_confirm_template</confirm_template>
        </email>
    </giftcards>
</default>
<adminhtml><layout><updates><blog><file>webtex/giftcards/giftcards.xml</file></blog></updates></layout></adminhtml>
<crontabs>
    <jobs>
        <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
        <run><model>giftcards/observer::sendEmailByDeliveryDate</model></run>
    </jobs>
</crontabs>
</config>
```

Thanks

Comment: how do you get this helper ? You should call `$helper = Mage::helper('giftcards');`

Comment: Yes @Alexandr Kapustin, Thats what I have tested on frontend, but I see exact this error on frontend as well.

Comment: Well, please show your files:

/app/code/local/Webtex/Giftcards/etc/config.xml

and 

/app/etc/modules/Webtex_Giftcards.xml

make sure that you have the same pathes for these files.

Comment: @Alexandr Kapustin I have updated my question with these files. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

My answer is quite similar to that of @Pedram Behroozi, I might have added it as a comment if it wasn't for the strange reputation limit on comments.

When I had this problem, it was because of confusion over the "module" attribute in adminhtml.xml.

```
<config>
  <menu>
    <catalog>
      <children>
        <productfeed translate="title" module="productfeed">
          <title>Product Data Feed</title>
          <action>adminhtml/productfeed/</action>
          <sort_order>90</sort_order>
        </productfeed>
      </children>
    </catalog>
  </menu>
</config>
```

Pedram is not *exactly* correct when he says the module name has to be lower case and without the namespace. When you provide a "translate" attribute then the corresponding "module" attribute is telling Magento what helper to use for that translation. So, what matters is that it exactly matches the node name inside the **helpers** node in config.xml. Mine was wrong because in that node I had included the namespace:

```
<config>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <etw_productfeed>
        <class>Etw_Productfeed_Helper</class>
      </etw_productfeed>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

In Alan Storm's article ["Admin Hello World Revisited"](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited) you can see he uses the namespace in his module references, and that still works. So either way is fine, as long as what's in adminhtml.xml matches what's in config.xml.

Comment: Just a note to remember this applies to all config files in the module: that is `adminhtml.xml`, `system.xml` and `widget.xml`

Comment: @Dough this is the right explanation regarding missing helper error.

Comment: Very helpful the Alan Storm's article "Admin Hello World Revisited"

Answer (score 2):

I faced this error twice and in both cases there was a problem inside my xml files.

My problems were not closing a tag (example):

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <!-- ... -->
    <routers>
```

And specifying the `module` attribute in the wrong way (in `etc/adminhtml.xml`):

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <report>
            <children>
                <foo_bar translate="title" module="bar"> <!-- module has to be lower case here and without the package name. Foo_Bar or Bar are wrong and cause the error. -->
                    <title>My own report</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/bar</action>
                </foo_bar>
            </children>
        </report>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Note the comment in the code above.

Unfortunately there's no easy way to check xml files for typos and mistakes, but one way would be comment out the codes part by part and see if the error goes away.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if compilation is enabled from admin > system > Tools > compilation. If you have added extension without disabling the compilation it may cause this problem. Clear cache & rerun the compilation process again. Hope this may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your module config.xml, You must define the Helpers node, otherwise it will always be looking for Mage_... Instead of Local or Community

`<global>
    <helpers>
        <mymodulename><class>XXX_YYY_Helper</class>
        </mymodulename>
    </helpers>
</global>`

Answer (score 0):

Your helper class should be like this,

```
class Webtex_Giftcards_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
// my methods
}
```

Check your extend class..
You should extend your class from

```
Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
```

Not from

```
Mage_Core_Helper_Data
```

Comment: I have tried you solution, but it didn't work also. error shows that class comes "Mage_" it means my class has not been found. I have checked config.xml as well and its also correct.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add frontName in frontend node

```
   <frontend>
            <routers>
                <giftcards>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Webtex_Giftcards</module>
                        <frontName>giftcards</frontName>
                    </args>
                </giftcards>
                <checkout>
                  <args>
                     <modules>
                         <Webtex_Giftcards before="Mage_Checkout">Webtex_Giftcards</Webtex_Giftcards>
                     </modules>
                 </args>
                </checkout>
            </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <giftcards>
                        <file>giftcards.xml</file>
                    </giftcards>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
```

hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

This Error is caused by autoloader file. To solve it don't use "_" in file name any where, specially in config.xml since, it will be replaced by "/" and throw such errors.

Ex:
giftcard_confirm.html

Insted use:
giftcardconfirm.html

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. I have check my config.xml and check my layout xml :

> ```
>   <layout>
>         <updates>
>             <module_name>
>                 <file>module_name.xml</file>
>             </module_name>
>         </updates>
>     </layout>
> ```

```
I have done mistake in module_name.xml. I have remove that code which is not needed.
```